# SQL UPDATE ARRAY

Tags: php, sql, arrays

My address bar is this: (it contains the job number 113852)

```
http://www.mysite.?0=113852
```

My array output is this: (it contains serial numbers... array amounts change)

```
Array ( [joblist] => Array ( [0] => gi4416ncd876 [1] => GI4521NA3391 [2] => M40719GD6274 ) [btnSubmit] => SUBMIT )
```

My php code:

```
$connection = mysql_connect('#', '#', '#'); 
mysql_select_db('#');

$equipmentquery="UPDATE tbl_assets 
SET date_installed = curdate(), account_number = {$_GET ['0']} 
WHERE serial = $_POST['joblist']";
```

I am getting a server error. How do I write this sql query to go thru the entire array and update my table?

Comment: I think your sql query string got syntax error. You could use {$_POST['joblist']}

Comment: oh holy hell!  NEVER NEVER NEVER directly use $_GET to interact with a SQL database!

Comment: your query is vulnerable to SQL INJECTION.

Comment: Also, mysql_*  is removed in PHP7 . You can use PDO.

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: Can you show the form that you're using? If you're not using one and/or the post method isn't set the `$_POST` array is never populated

Comment: I did a Print_r ($_POST) it outputs: Array ( [joblist] => Array ( [0] => gi4416ncd876 [1] => GI4521NA3391 [2] => M40719GD6274 ) [btnSubmit] => SUBMIT )

Comment: Since joblist is an array your query will always have an error. `echo $_POST['joblist'];`

Answer (score 2):

You have space between $_GET and [0], and I think in $_POST['joblist'] there are missing {}.

But you should escape values before put them into query!

Comment: $equipmentquery="UPDATE tbl_assets SET date_installed = curdate(), account_number = {$_GET['0']} WHERE serial = {$_POST['joblist']}";

Comment: I think values should be put in '' as far as I remember. Try to escape values and put variables into query, usign '$variable' . It's MySQL or PostgreSQL?

Comment: MySQL... obviously I'm a noob but I am not understanding what you are referring to with the variable comment. @Grzegorz J

Comment: It was just a simple example, try to:
[link](http://php.net/manual/pl/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)
Then put your escaped variables into query, and put them in single quotes.